# How to add values to `import.meta`

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to add values to `import.meta` in a global fashion but it doesn't seem to work in Node.js:

```js
// a.mjs

import './b.mjs'
console.log('[a.mjs] import.meta.env.DEV', import.meta.env?.DEV)
```

```js
// b.mjs

import.meta.env = { DEV: true }
console.log('[b.mjs] import.meta.env.DEV', import.meta.env.DEV)
```

Running `$ node a.mjs` logs:

```
[b.mjs] import.meta.env.DEV true
[a.mjs] import.meta.env.DEV undefined
```

Is there a way to add values to `import.meta` that persist across files?

Note that a global variable `globalThis.DEV` wouldn't work because my use case requires the global variable to match [Vite's `import.meta.env.DEV`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables).

Comment: `import.meta` contains information about the current module. If you want to make something global there is actually an object you can use for this, it is called `global`

Comment: What node version are you using? maybe it's possible to set a .env file so you can configure env from there without any extra library https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.6.0

Comment: I'm aware of `global`/`globalThis` but it needs to be `import.meta.env`. I updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: @Sombriks It doesn't set `import.meta.env` but [only `process.env`](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs). (I'm the author of [Vike](https://vike.dev/) and I'm trying to make Vike to set the correct `import.meta.env` values for the use and I can't ask users to use Node.js flags.)

Comment: @brillout Did you look at the vite source to understand how it sets `import.meta.env`?

Comment: @Bergi Vite statically replaces `import.meta.env` values and the issue here is that it doesn't work for externalized libraries (since Vite doesn't process them). That's why we want to set `import.meta.env` values at runtime (instead of compile time)

Comment: @brillout Given that `import.meta` is a different object in every module, you'd have to (statically) add code to every module to set its own `import.meta.env`. I don't think there's a hook in the module loader to do that (yet) - but I'm not really clear whether you want to do this in nodejs or on the client side, and which module loader even is used there.

Comment: @Bergi The tricky part is making `import.meta.env.DEV` work for files living in `node_modules/` that Vite doesn't transpile. For these files we need to be able to set `import.meta.env.DEV` in a global fashion at run-time. I was hoping some dirty trick may do the job. But I guess Node.js injects a different `import` for each file as a closure, so I don't think it's possible (but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: @brillout I dunno, you might be able to hook into nodejs to add a `import.meta.env = process.env;` statement to each module. It seems this is possible with the [module loader hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#customization-hooks), and would also apply to modules loaded from `node_modules/`, but I have not worked with this myself.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to do things that aren't meant to be done. What exactly are you trying to achieve in your app? Maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @zoran404 "you are trying to do things that aren't meant to be done" Is that true? It would be a glaring hole if the spec didn't foresee that frameworks may want to set the values of `import.meta.env`. (I'm the author of [Vike](https://vike.dev/).) If anything I'd be inclind to say it's a Node.js bug: what Vike wants to do is very much expected.

Comment: Based on what do you believe that it is very much expected that node should support this?

Comment: @brillout I think you should open an issue in the nodejs repository, stating your goal and asking what they think would be the best way to achieve that. Maybe in the next nodejs release there's a specific loader hook that lets you build/extend the `import.meta` object depending on the module

Comment: I would say that using query parameters on the URLs of modules would be easier (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta#passing_query_parameters)); you can add them pretty much indiscriminately to the URLs of modules under `node_modules`...